# Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have created a new user 'dad' on my macbook pro (OSX 10.8.4). 'dad' is an administrator. I've successfully installed homebrew as 'dad'. It was previously installed by another user. I did:

```
sudo chown -R dad /usr/local/
cd /usr/local/
chmod -R 777 *
```

But any attempt to install, e.g:

```
brew install nmap
```

Gives:

```
Error: Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing
```

It seems nmap.brewing doesn't exist:

```
dad$ ls -l /usr/local/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing
ls: /usr/local/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing: No such file or directory

dad$ ls -l /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing
ls: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/nmap.brewing: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 156):

Fixed.

It seemed I needed to take ownership of /Library/Caches/Homebrew

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Caches/Homebrew/
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I only had to change the user to the user I was trying to install the library in. **sudo chown -R user /Library/Caches/Homebrew/**

Comment: Not working :( brew install libiconv (...) Error: Permission denied -  Users/myusername/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libiconv/01.configure

Comment: Thanks this helped with an install of Homebrew using Chef. Thought it was a Chef issue, was permissions. Great to know!

Comment: Fixing all warnings in `brew doctor` output was helpful for me.

Comment: Why does OS X ship with a package manager that doesn't work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 31):

Searching the [brew manpage](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/manpages/brew.1.md) for `/Library/Caches/Homebrew`, it turns out that you can set the directory that homebrew uses for caching with the the `HOMEBREW_CACHE` environment variable, or just create `~/Library/Caches/Homebrew`. These approaches will be easier than the `chown` approach if you’re a non-administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the below command:

sudo chmod -R g+w /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/

sudo chgrp -R staff /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/

Answer (score 1):

mkdir -p ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew
echo 'export HOMEBREW_CACHE=~/Library/Caches/Homebrew' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

Since user doesn't have permission, just use command

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/homebrew
```

Comment: because user doesn't have permission